# Proof of nonnegative,decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is a nonnegative,decreasing function on $[1,\infty]$.Prove that for every $n\ge2$,
$$\sum_{j=2}^nf(j)\leq \int_{x=1}^nf(x) \mathrm{d}x \le \sum_{j=1}^nf(j)$$
 I think I need to show that the first summation is less than or equal to the upper Riemann sum of the integral and then show the lower Riemann sum is less than or equal to the second summation.

I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you partition at the integers: $1,2,3,4,\dots$

Comment: If I partition at integers n=1,2,3.... Then I think U(f,P)= summation j=1,n f(x(j-1))*1?

Comment: ...and what is $L(f,P)$

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Int(f, x = 1 to n) = Int(f, x = 1 to 2) + Int(f, x = 2 to 3) +...+ Int(f, x = n - 1 to n). Since f(k+1) < Int(f, x = k to k + 1) < f(k), let k runs from 1 to n and add all inequalities we get the answer.